# Plotly bubble chart - How to change several aspects like scalebar, popup lable, and my x-axis tick error?

Tags: python, plotly

```
Bldt = [go.Scatter(x=BBdata['horsepower'],
               y=BBdata['mpg'],
               text=BBdata['name'],
               mode='markers',
               marker=dict
                   (size=BBdata['weight']/240, 
                    color=BBdata['acceleration'], 
                    showscale=True,))]

Bllayout = go.Layout(title='Bubble Chart',
                    xaxis={'title':'Horsepower'},
                    yaxis=dict(title='mpg'),
                    hovermode='closest')
Blfig = go.Figure(data=Bldt, layout=Bllayout)

Blfig.update_layout(title_text='Bubble Chart', title_x=0.5)
```

This is 5th day I learn python, I do not have programming or coding exp before so it is very challenging. I would like to ask something about the code I wrote above.

1. I want to add a title to the scale bar because it represents a 3rd information which is 'acceleration', and how to change the color?
2. My X-axis data ranges from 40 to 210, but in this chart, it is only displayed until 100. Why?
3. I want to change the popup info when pointing to a bubble so it will inform us like this:

   "Car Name (BOLD)"
   Mpg:
   Horsepower:
   Acceleration:

my default setting layout is:
("Mpg Value, Horsepower)
"Car Name"

Is it possible to do that? Because I'm a newbie something I don't know if my default setting is already changed, this is for my second course, and the result that I got when running the code is always different from my course video just like the error in this one even the code is exactly the same. What should I do? Should I reinstall it so the lib will revert to default setting?

[image]

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then edit your question accordingly. Multiple questions rarely get good answers.

Comment: Break your problems down into entities. For instance, why are the x- data are only shown up to 100? When looking at it, you might notice that the ticks are evenly spaced. Are the data evenly spaced? No. And what number is `?`, and why is `220` between `96` and `100`? Probably, because you forgot to convert this dataframe column into float or integer values, so plotly uses the strings `96`, `220`, and `100`, sorts them lexically, and plots them against the index `1,2,3...`. There: One problem less. Next.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is imho very helpful for beginners.

Comment: Is the x-axis value a string, check the horsepower column in `BBdata.info()`. If I had that and the sample data you are using for the visualization, I might have gotten an answer sooner. Can you provide the sample data?